# End infinte loop in mac terminal .app

Tags: macos

I made a program that keeps refreshing my page in firefox, and when I run it in Terminal, it's easy to quit (^C) but how do I do that when I've saved it as an application? After I quit it, it keeps running the command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it in Activity Monitor and kill it or `killall app_name` from the Terminal, where "app_name" is whatever you saved the executable as.